# Content of sections overlapping

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

I have a code similar to

```
\section{1}
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/img1}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/img2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\section{2}
\input{figures/fig1}

\pagebreak

\input{figures/fig2}

\pagebreak

\input{figures/fig3}
```

Unfortunately, when compiling the figures appear within the first section, and not in section 2. Why is that so?

Comment: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144) might be worth having a look at.

Comment: Out of curiosity and certainly not related to the placement issue: why do you use a minipage environment inside of  each of the figure environments?

Comment: `[hbt!]`  prevents the figures going at the top of the page, or on a page of figures (the two most common places) so makes it very likely the figures can not be placed anywhere.

Comment: For that matter, why are you using a figure with no caption and no text to float around?

Comment: @JohnKormylo just for example, of course they have more data leandriis to center them DavidCarlisle Just [h] is better, I guess. Actually changed from that because I thought it might be a solution